# How to minimize the placements of CDN?

Tags: html, requirejs, cdn

I'm using bootstrap and jQuery CDN for my web app and I'm just wondering is there a way to not having to go to bunch of my files and paste the CDN links and scripts and instead just put it all in one place?

Let's say that I can't save bootstrap or jQuery locally or make the web app a single page web app.

I believe Require.js can do this but I'm not sure how or is there another JavaScript libraries that can do this?

Comment: Using CDN is recommended (instead of having local copies), as it can make uses of caching. Avoid having local copies of JS unless you're working in Intranet (with no Internet available).

Answer (score 0):

First let me state the obvious, that most CDN's include minified versions already.. but there are several options to do this on your own. [See here for others](http://bfy.tw/27jh).

I've used this one, [JShrink](https://github.com/tedious/JShrink).

Here's an example using a list of CDNs:

To include your scripts..

```
$scripts = array(
    "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js",
    "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"
);

foreach($scripts as $script) 
    echo "<script src='minifier.php?url=".urlencode($script)."'></script>\n";
```

Then `minifier.php` looks like this..

```
<?php
include('vendor/autoload.php');
$minifiedCode = \JShrink\Minifier::minify(file_get_contents($_GET['script']));
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
echo $minifiedCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject any CDN in your page's header using the below Javascript in your javascript file of the app. But you at least need same javascript file linked in all pages with this script.

```js
function loadjscss(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined"){
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
}

loadjscss("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js", "js");

loadjscss("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css", "css");
```